# How to remove extra blank space from website?

Tags: html, css

I have an inhouse developed website for doing Home Inspections [www.e-ghar.com](http://www.e-ghar.com). But I am facing a issue on its home page. The home page shows an extra blank space on the right side when viewed on a smaller screen. Can any expert of CSS help me in identification of issue?

Comment: `#fwslider .slideNext` has `right: -50px;` correct it

Comment: Please provide [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) of your problem

Comment: @mmushtaq he has already given link of whole site..why fiddle is needed?

Comment: I don't get why he has been downvoted

Comment: @superuser solution has solved it

Comment: lol... @mnemosdev sometimes its destiny and sometime its politics ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is two way to resolve your problem.

**quick fix**

```
body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

**Or actual fixes**

```
.tt-wrapper { 
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: It worked! Thanks Super User

Comment: http://imgur.com/ijU2bjj is the view after correct. Community Support Works as charm. Great Support Thanks Again

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj we are here to help..but test once again as i can still see gap.. but if its working for you then ok

Comment: @Leothelion you may be correct. i will get it tested exhaustively. As of now it looks okay. Updated our live Home Inspection site at www.e-ghar.com

Comment: @Leothelion. you were correct problem is solved only in desktop browser (when we resize the screen). The blank space still exist in mobile browsers

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj told you because overflow will remove scroll bar but not the blank space.

Comment: What can be suitable solution for the problem?

Comment: @AbhinavBhardwaj you can check updated answer to resolve your problem

Answer (score 0):

Try to something like this.

```
 #fwslider {
    overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Comment: Its not working. Please test first then post. Thank you

Comment: Same.. it also not worked. http://imgur.com/MxVUBHL

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
#fwslider {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: Why not? That's the solution for the question.

Comment: That was the closest thing to select. Although it might provide an answer you might explain a bit of the why and how. Provide a bit more background to the solution. Currently, although it is an answer, it is more suitable as a comment.

Comment: It didnot worked for me. Gives following screen http://imgur.com/MxVUBHL

Answer (score 0):

Looks like all you need is [`box-sizing: border-box`](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_box-sizing.asp).

`box-sizing: border-box` includes the padding and border in the width.

```
* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

If you do this, you will have to change your `.product1_of_3` to:

```
.product1_of_3 {
    float: left;
    width: 29.3333%;
    padding: 2%;
    margin: 0 2%;
    background: #ffffff;
}
```

Comment: Chris thanks for support. didnot got a chance to try as the overflow-x: hidden in body simply worked for me.